# Extend a fluent API from external package in go

Tags: go, fluent

I've currently got an object from an external package that provides a fluent API, like:

```
thing := ext.GetThing()
thing.do().stuff()
```

I'd like to extend this to provide a new function `cool` so I can use it like

```
thing.do().cool().stuff()
```

Unfortunately, since I can't have an external type as a receiver for `cool`, then best I've got so far seems to be

```
cool(thing.do()).stuff()
```

which becomes very difficult to read as I combine my custom stuff with the built-in fluent.

Is there some way in Go to achieve the extended fluent style that I'm missing?

Comment: 1. "Fluent" APIs are not really idiomatic in Go (and not that useful as e.g. in Java) and 2. No you cannot do this.

Comment: @Volker 1. I'm just working with what I've got, 2. if it's provably impossible, can you make that an answer

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't because you "cannot define new methods on a non-local type", as the compiler will tell you if you try.

Let's say you want to do something silly like:

```
import "net/http"

func (c *http.Client) SayHi() {
    println("Hi!")
}
```

This won't compile and you'll get the error message mentioned above as you can check here: https://play.golang.org/p/FxBMAfR_aN